# How to embed this php code in html?

Tags: php, html

I decided to build a booking calendar and embed it to my website. But I don't know how to include it in the html file. I tried the `<?php ?>` tag but it doesn't display at all. I looked around and found this htaccess file thing. How do I generate it? Is it a way to use my php code without this?

Here is what included in my big html file (I did not include other html here)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hmtl>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include 'calendar.php';
        $calendar = new Calendar();

        echo $calendar->show();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I used sublime text edit and there is no "color" on the key words meaning it is not recognizing the php tag.

Comment: what is your file saved as ?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad for SO's Q&A format. There are too many things here to easily address in a single answer, and there's not enough information for us to know what's going wrong. I'd really recommend finding a tutorial on setting up a web application server to run PHP instead of putting a question here. When you run into a more specific problem you're more likely to find a good answer here.

Comment: I also use sublime, that means your file is not saved with .php ext

Answer (score 0):

Place the php code of the calendar in a file and save it as say, `calendar.php` and then add the following line in the pages where you want the calendar to appear in:

```
<?php include("calendar.php"); ?>
```

---

**N.B.** Make sure to replace the file extension of all your html files with `.php` extension instead of the `.html` extension.

**For example:** `index.html` should be `index.php`